# window.location.replace() not firing in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

I am trying to cause a webpage to reload (when the conditions are right) with a different parameter in the URL GET string.  The code below works in all browsers except Google Chrome.  In Chrome, it doesn't work the first time it happens, but if I reload the page then it always works.

```
// Grab the current URL and put it into a string for evaluation. 
var url = window.location.toString();

// See if the sort parameter is in the URL.  If so, then hide the page,
// change the sort value, and replace this page with the right one.
if (url.indexOf("sort=rc") == -1 && (localStorage.getItem("sortValue") != "Room" || localStorage.getItem("sortValue") == null)) {
    Bootstrapper.MVT.injectCSS("body { display:none; }");
    var newUrl= url.replace("sort=rt", "sort=rc");
    window.location.replace(newUrl);
}
```

When I step through the code with the Chrome debugger, it correctly goes into the if statement, hides the  tag, changes the URL to have the new sort value, and seems to run the window.location.replace call but doesn't reload the page.  The page finishes loading, but it's blank because of the display none call.  If I click the reload button, the page reloads with the desired sort value, everything displays, and I never have this problem again until I clear the cache.

Any ideas as to why Chrome goes over the window.location.replace call but doesn't force the page to reload?

Comment: are you waiting until the `window.onload` event has occurred before execution?

Comment: `window.location` is an object, not a string.

Comment: @WhiteHat - I tried your suggestion, but it doesn't matter if I wait for the `onload` event before trying to call `window.location.replace()`.  It still seems to ignore the replace call.

Comment: I never figured this bug out.  I eventually tackled the problem from a different direction that avoided the use of window.location.replace().  It took another 3 days to rewrite everything and thoroughly test it, but now I have a working solution.

Comment: `window.location.replace()` is not working consistently in Google Chrome, you might want to try using `window.location.href` for better cross-browser compatibility